# Cocos2D: How to animate hero moves

Tags: iphone, ios5, cocos2d-iphone

I have hero Sprite which i move by joypad.

I want to animate hero moves!

How I can to this? During hero move his position to play animation?

Can some one give me example source?

Answer (score 1):

Cocos2d has good example code included with it, including animation examples.

Answer (score 0):

You're likely to want to use a sequence of frames to achieve the blast animation. Have a look at [CCAnimation](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.5/interface_c_c_animation.html) for the coding and [Zwoptex](http://zwoptexapp.com/) for the creation of spritesheets. Good luck!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the best example for animation in cocos2d. Click [Here.](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1271/how-to-use-animations-and-sprite-sheets-in-cocos2d)